# Php AppEngine Environmental Variable for UTF-8

Tags: php, google-app-engine, environment-variables, yaml

I need to set the Environmental Variable for UTF-8 in my Php AppEngine app.yaml file but can not find or guess the correct syntax. Tried the following

env_variables:
- DEFAULT_ENCODING: 'UTF-8'

but no cigar. What is it or where can I find it or a Sample yaml with a few other entries?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the same as Python.

Docs here with examples:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables

Comment: That doesn't answer it. Yes You can define variables in app.yaml to make them available to the program's os.environ dictionary but what is the exact abc's of the term. Its not rocket science but its also not listed anywhere I can find, and every guess so far has been wrong. I need something like the following two short words, but for utf-8 that works
>>>env_variables:
 >>> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'

Comment: Where can I get a list of all the envir terms and their exact spelling?